# Close SublimeText sidebar on load

Tags: sublime-text-3

I have a project saved without the sidebar opened. But whenever I quit and restart SublimeText without closing the project, the project reopens with the sidebar opened.

It became irritating when I have multiple projects opened and have to close every single one manually. How can I make the sidebar close by default?

SublimeText Build 3059.

Answer (score 0):

In the same directory as your `.sublime-project` file, try looking for a similarly-named `.sublime-workspace` file and deleting that. You'll lose track of which windows/tabs were opened in the project, but once you save it again that data will be regenerated.

Comment: Hm..tried deleting the .sublime-workspace file. Didn't work. Tried overwriting the .sublime-workspace file with sidebar closed. Didn't work too (as in quit and reopen sublime with the sidebar closed).